# Scrapy doesn't get <time> value

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape this site:
https://www.reuters.com/companies/PIH.OQ/financials/income-statement-quarterly

But I can't extract the time-values - the output looks like:

```
<time class=""TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg""></time>
```

Here my python code

```
import scrapy
class ScrapeTableSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'reuters'

    start_urls = ['https://www.reuters.com/companies/PIH.OQ/financials/income-statement-annual']

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.reuters.com/companies/PIH.OQ/financials/income-statement-annual',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

            yield {
                'Test': response.xpath('//*[@class="tables-container"]//table//thead//tr//th//time').getall(),
            }
```

Comment: did you check it in web browser - in my browser I see `<time>`  without value.

Comment: I checked it again - this value is added by JavaScript ... but `Scrapy` can't run JavaScript. You will have to use Scrapy with Selenium to control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: I found dates (with all other values) in JSON file but I don't know if Scrapy will read it correctly https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyFinancials/PIH.OQ If it can read it correctly then you may no need read HTML and get all from this JSON which python can easily convert to dictionary.

Comment: wow thanks a lot! getting the data in JSON seems to be even better for my use case. do you mind asking how you found/identified this api-link?

Comment: find it in browser Developer Tool -> Network -> XHR.

Comment: as @SamsulIslam alread mentioned: I opened `Developer Tool` in Firefox/Chrome (shortcut `F12`), change tab to `Network`, set filter `XHR` (which means `AJAX`), and reload page - and then it shows all files/urls/requests loaded by this page (filtered to AJAX requests) and then I click on links and see what these links sends to browser - if it is JSON data then I manually search information which I can see in your table on page - and I saw text from table `Total Premiums Earned` so I start checking if there is date which you are searching.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse json from the HTML page like the following.

```
import scrapy
import chompjs

class ScrapeTableSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'reuters'

    start_urls = ['https://www.reuters.com/companies/PIH.OQ/financials/income-statement-annual']

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
        'https://www.reuters.com/companies/PIH.OQ/financials/income-statement-annual',
    ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        javascript=response.css('script::text')[3].get()
        table_data =chompjs.parse_js_object(javascript)
        dates = table_data['props']['initialState']['markets']['financials']['financial_tables']['income_interim_tables'][0]['headers']
        # for example: ['2020-09-30', '2020-06-30', '2020-03-31', '2019-12-31', '2019-09-30']

        yield {
            'dates': dates
        }
```